# Summing values on 1d NumPy array inside a cuda-compiled kernel results in error, but doc says its supported?

Tags: python, arrays, gpgpu, numpy-ndarray, numba

I'm trying to sum the values of an array inside a CUDA-compled Numba function.

I have a simple test code like so:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda

values = np.zeros(100, dtype=np.float64)
values.fill(1)


@cuda.jit
def try_to_sum(arr):
    print(arr.sum())


d_values = cuda.to_device(values)
cuda.synchronize()

try_to_sum[1, 1](d_values)
```

The doc says this is a supported function:

But it fails with:

```
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.nditer' or unsupported use of the function.

File "../../anaconda3/envs/GpuVM/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/np/arraymath.py", line 167:
    def array_sum_impl(arr):
        <source elided>
        c = zero
        for v in np.nditer(arr):
        ^

During: typing of get attribute at /home/stark/anaconda3/envs/GpuVM/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/np/arraymath.py (167)

File "../../anaconda3/envs/GpuVM/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/np/arraymath.py", line 167:
    def array_sum_impl(arr):
        <source elided>
        c = zero
        for v in np.nditer(arr):
        ^

During: lowering "$8call_method.3 = call $6load_method.2(func=$6load_method.2, args=[], kws=(), vararg=None)" at /home/stark/Work/mmr-evolution-gpu/xtests.py (10)
```

I also tried using `np.cumsum(arr)`, but it fails with:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.cumsum' or unsupported use of the function.

File "xtests.py", line 10:
def try_to_sum(arr):
    np.cumsum(arr)
    ^
```

How can I do a simple sum of an 1d array containing float64 values inside a CUDA kernel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, I was looking at the CPU docs... the CUDA section states array functions are not supported. So this is not supported. I'll have to keep the sum in a scalar variable along with the array in order to accomplish things fast.

I'll leave it here in case it helps someone else.